# How to query a self-referential comments table to find the comments with replies, ordered by the latest replies?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, self-referencing-table

In an app I'm working in, I've got a Comments table in my Postgres DB that which can be simplified to something like this:

```
+----+-----------+-----------------+---------------------+
| id | parent_id | group_member_id |     created_at      |
+----+-----------+-----------------+---------------------+
| 1  | NULL      | 1               | 2023-08-01 12:00:00 |
| 2  | NULL      | 2               | 2023-08-01 12:00:01 |
| 3  | NULL      | 2               | 2023-08-01 12:00:02 |
| 4  | 3         | 1               | 2023-08-01 12:00:03 |
| 5  | 2         | 1               | 2023-08-01 12:00:04 |
| 6  | 1         | 1               | 2023-08-01 12:00:05 |
| 7  | 2         | 2               | 2023-08-01 12:00:06 |
| 8  | 2         | 1               | 2023-08-01 12:00:07 |
+----+-----------+-----------------+---------------------+
```

The `parent_id` column, when populated, refers to another row in the comment table. This sets up a parent/child relationship. In other words, a comment can have other comments that are replies. Any parent comment can have many replies. For the purposes of this app, the comment parent/child relationship is only one level deep.

There's also a Group Members table that is referenced by the comments table via a foreign key. This represents each comment's author, and can be reduced to this:

```
+----+---------------+
| id |     name      |
+----+---------------+
|  1 | Johnny Tables |
|  2 | Susan Select  |
+----+---------------+
```

For any given group member, I want to find the latest distinct root comments to which they've replied, in the order they've replied to them. For instance, `Johnny Tables` (id 1) would get:

```
+----+-----------+-----------------+---------------------+
| id | parent_id | group_member_id |     created_at      |
+----+-----------+-----------------+---------------------+
|  2 | NULL      |               2 | 2023-08-01 12:00:01 |
|  1 | NULL      |               1 | 2023-08-01 12:00:00 |
|  3 | NULL      |               2 | 2023-08-01 12:00:02 |
+----+-----------+-----------------+---------------------+
```

And `Susan Select` (id 2) would get:

```
+----+-----------+-----------------+---------------------+
| id | parent_id | group_member_id |     created_at      |
+----+-----------+-----------------+---------------------+
|  2 | NULL      |               2 | 2023-08-01 12:00:01 |
+----+-----------+-----------------+---------------------+
```

[Here is a fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-_obBrX6) that sets up the table structure with sample data.

I've tried various incantations with subqueries and `DISTINCT` and `ORDER BY`, but I'm missing something. With this query, for example, I seem to get the correct replies, but they don't actually get ordered by the `created_at` date. They're ordered by ascending `parent_id`s

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (parent_id)
    parent_id,
    created_at
FROM
    comments
WHERE
    comments.group_member_id = 1
    AND comments.parent_id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
    comments.parent_id,
    comments.created_at DESC
```

And once I have that, I don't quite know how to leverage that to get the root comments and keep them in the chronological order of the replies. What am I missing?

*Note: While I'm asking for general SQL guidance here, since the app I'm working on is a Rails app, an Active Record or Arel interpretation would also be welcome.*

**EDIT:** Added sample tables and expected results.

Comment: Please update your question with sample data and the expected/desired results of that data. Add these as formatted text (see [here](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/)) - **no images**.  Further a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) would be appreciated.

Comment: you would need to use recursive cte

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: Thanks for the formatted sample data tip @Belayer, I've added that.

Comment: @nbk Give that I've clarified the question with some sample data and the desired result, can you expand on how you might use recursive common table expressions to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fiddle data looks to have the `parent_id` and `group_member_id` columns transposed.

Since there is only a single-level in the root/child comment hierarchy, you have overcomplicated your query.

This is a simple `group by` with a join back into the root comment:

```
select gm.name, r.id, r.group_member_id, r.parent_id, r.created_at,
       max(c.created_at) as last_reply_at
  from comments c
       join group_members gm on gm.id = c.group_member_id
       join comments r on r.id = c.parent_id
 group by gm.name, r.id, r.group_member_id, r.parent_id, r.created_at
 order by gm.name, max(c.created_at) desc;
```

Updated [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bK4WucXO)

Comment: Thank you so much, Mike! I still haven't fully wrapped my head around `group by` clauses, so this is extremely helpful.

Comment: @MichaelBester  If simplifying further helps you, then please try thinking about the query without the join back into `comments r`.  The only reason I joined back to `comments r` is because it looked like you wanted the entire row for the root comment.  The first step is "give me all the latest (by `created_at`) comments by `group_member_id` per `parent_id` from the `comments` table."  You can then order by the latest `created_at`.  The join back to `comments r` does not figure into the selection or ordering of rows--it's there only to get those root comment columns.